# How do I implement Algolia Search filtering in a React Native Modal component?

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, filtering, algolia

I am using Algolia search in my React Native app, following the instructions in [guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/native/react/#overview)

I have created a `RefinementList` as per the instructions, and this works fine when placed directly with the app, as per

```
<InstantSearch
  searchClient={searchClient}
  indexName={THE_INDEX}
  root={root}
>
  <RefinementList attribute="brand.name" />
  <SearchBox />
  <InfiniteHits />
</InstantSearch>
```

When this runs and I enter a search term I happily get a list of my faceted brand names.  But I need this to work within a modal.  So following Algolia's instructions I have created a `Filters` component and use my `RefinementList` from within that instead:

```
<InstantSearch
  searchClient={searchClient}
  indexName={THE_INDEX}
  root={root}
  searchState={this.state.searchState}
  onSearchStateChange={this.onSearchStateChange}
>
  <Filters
    isModalOpen={this.state.isModalOpen}
    toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
    indexName={THE_INDEX}
    searchClient={searchClient}
    searchState={this.state.searchState}
    onSearchStateChange={this.onSearchStateChange}
  />
  <SearchBox />
  <FilterButton
    onFilter={this.toggleModal}
  />
  <InfiniteHits />
</InstantSearch>
```

However the modal is always empty.  The console shows that when the `RefinementList` is simply a child of the `InstantSearch` then its `items` array gets populated, but when the `RefinementList` is invoked within the `Filters` component then it's empty.  The `Filters` component is exactly as per Algolia's docs, apart from the fact I pass in the `indexName` as a prop.  I've checked in the React Native debugger and the `RefinementList` has access to the same `context`, the `searchState` is being set, and `onSearchStateChange` is being invoked correctly. The `indexName` is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I had to add a 'virtual' `SearchBox`, ala

```
const VirtualSearchBox = connectSearchBox(() => null)
```

which is used as a child of the `InstantSearch` component in the `Filters` component, making `Filters` more like

```
const Filters = ({
  isModalOpen,
  searchState,
  searchClient,
  toggleModal,
  onSearchStateChange,
  indexName
}) => (
  <Modal animationType="slide" visible={isModalOpen}>
    <SafeAreaView>
      <InstantSearch
        searchClient={searchClient}
        indexName={indexName}
        searchState={searchState}
        onSearchStateChange={onSearchStateChange}
      >
        <VirtualSearchBox />
        <RefinementList attribute="brand" />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeButton} onPress={toggleModal}>
          <Text style={styles.closeButtonText}>Close</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </InstantSearch>
    </SafeAreaView>
  </Modal>
)
```

Inside the modal the `searchState` is always falsy because the `SearchBox` is not mounted.

Each time a request happens inside the modal the emtpy state will be provided.

The refinements inside the `searchState` are not enough to apply a refinement on the search parameters. All of the widgets associated with the refinement have to be mounted (ref: [Search State docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/widgets/customize-an-existing-widget/react/#the-search-state-format-explained)).